# Django with MongoEngine and/or MongoDB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

OK, I'm looking to get into mongodb big-time, but I need installation assistance.

Here's the stack I'd like to use:

- Linux 12.04 LTS (installed, configured, secured)
- Python 2.7
- Virtualenv as a container
- Gunicorn for WSGI
- Django 1.6.2
- Nginx as the reverse-proxy/webserver

Now, here's where I'm needing assistance: I want to run mongodb as my database and I saw MongoEngine as an option. Problem is, I'm not sure if mongoengine is simply the ORM layer or does it contain an installation of mongodb with it?

The other question is, do I need to install mongoengine (and mongodb, if necessary) in the virtual environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MongoEngine is an Object-Document Mapper, written in Python for working with MongoDB.

It connects to your MongoDB database and is just the ORM layer. It uses pymongo the official python driver for mongodb and at any point should you need to you can connect directly with pymongo.

You will need a database (mongodb) running somewhere - so that must be installed - see the [Installation guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! OK so I can install MongoDB outside of my virtualenv setup and connect to it from MongoEngine?